# Why is the cosmological constant is taken to be a free parameter if its experimental value is $\sim 10^{-52}$?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, cosmological-constant, neutron-stars

I have been studying a [paper](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1502.02929) on neutron stars in Einstein-$\Lambda$ gravity. In this paper, the cosmological constant is considered a free parameter.

Now, isn't the cosmological constant already known to be of orders of $10^{-52}$? Why do we consider it a variable?

I would be thankful for any possible answers and references.

Comment: It looks like the paper just studies some various values of $\Lambda$, and we of course want predictions from different sources/measurements to not be in conflict with one another. The paper says that neutron star structure is consistent with non-negative $\Lambda$, as one would expect.

Comment: you are saying known, but we cannot actually measure it..so thats a theoretical value for LCDM...

Answer (score 2):

The cosmological constant *is* a free parameter. In the paper, they appear to use a range of values for $\Lambda$ and study the predictions, to see what values of $\Lambda$ are consistent with observation. As (hopefully) expected, it's found that a small positive cosmological constant is consistent with their models. Essentially, they're just looking at the different effects on neutron star structure with different values of $\Lambda$.

This is all summed up in the closing remarks:

> Our results showed that, when the approximate value of the cosmological constant was $10^{−52}$ $m^{−2}$, this constant did
> not play a sensitive role in the structure of neutron stars, but by taking larger values for it (about $\Lambda > 10^{−14} $m$^{−2}$
> ),
> the maximum mass and its radius were reduced.

Answer (score -1):

The reference you identified in your post seems to be out of date. In most sources I see, the value of the cosmological constant is about 0.7, and is represented as Omega_Lambda. I suggest you take a look at
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Detailed_derivation for a very relevant equation. Keep in mind that the sum of the four Omega variables equals 1.

Comment: It is very commonplace to use a range of values of $\Lambda$ for numerical plots & simulations. Also the reference is not out of date (it's only 2017!), and the authors clearly know the observed/implied value of $\Lambda$: in the closing remarks they say "when the approximate value of the cosmological constant was $10^{−52}$m$^{−2}$...", which is the current best estimate.

Comment: The technical term "cosmological constant" seems to have a variety of meanings. The meaning I am familiar with is that represented in the Friedman equation as Omega_Lambda, which has no units. The meaning you described with a value of 10^-53 m^-2 has no explanation that I am able to understand. I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: You're talking about the cosmological constant *density parameter*. If you restore units, it indeed has dimension length$^{-2}$. Take a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant , you'll see your $\Omega \approx 0.7$ is the same as the value I quoted in units.

Comment: Thank you for Wikipedia article. I now get that there is a Λ symbol called a  cosmological constant as well as the Ω_Λ variable. However, in reading though the article, I am still confused about the concept. In the General Relativity equation in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity#Cosmology, Λ is the coefficient of the term g_μν, but due to my ignorance regarding tensor notations, I do not have any understanding of  the concept which Λ represent, and how it relates to Ω_Λ, or ρ_Λ.